# Trouble logging in to Restful API using Http Request in Node-Red

Tags: jquery, node-red

After what seems like eternity reading stack posts about Http Request, I'm finally breaking down to create an account and ask for help. I am trying to read data via Restful API in Node-Red on a Pi to eventually be displayed on a Dashboard.

The device hosting data has a white paper on using Restful API.

The first piece, which seems like it should be easiest is to login to the device. The screenshot is from the white paper on using plain text login an JQuery. After trying forever to get a Function block to do this, I've read many posts saying the Http Request should be able to handle this, but it always replies the same results (which is not "signin done").

Genuinely hoping the format of the screenshot can be easily configured in a Http Request, but willing to learn/read/edit whatever is necessary.

Thanks in advance.
[Whitepaper Screenshot of Login Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w55a.png)

Have tried Function block using screenshot as syntax as well as endless iterations of Http Request properties.

Code from Screenshot.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.10.11/sdcard/cpt/app/signin.php",
       type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',
       data: {
              'user[name]': 'admin',
              'user[password]': 'hellocpt'
             }
      }).done(function(data) {
         console.debug("signin done");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the code as a code block in the question rather than as a screen shot.

Comment: You also need to show us what you've tried with the HTTP-request node